# date input type not showing in IE 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, datepicker

I have IE 10 and tried to view an example of the input date type. but the textbox is just a plain text box no date picker. What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com's compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), the only current browsers that support `<input type="date">` are Chrome, Opera, and iOS Safari.

Comment: Any alternative for this? I really thought HTML5 will be for the modern web, are dates not important for the modern web? Is the modern web all about writing blogs full of alphanumeric text?

Answer (score 0):

You need a javascript framework like angularjs to do the trick i.e. make it browser friendly.